Create a new operator for an existing class
I'm working in C++ with a C library that uses a lot of pointers in its API.
To make things work without being annoyed by memory management, I'm using extensively std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr, but when it comes to calling the internal C function, I have a bunch of get() calls, which I find annoying.
Is there a smart way to make the compiler implicitly call the get() function itself when it detects that the raw pointer is needed, and that a std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr is given ?
I know it can be done by writing an explicit wrapper around std::shared_ptr like the following:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class SharedPtrWrapper {
public:
    // Constructor
    explicit SharedPtrWrapper(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}

    // Overload the dereference operator
    T& operator*() const {
        return *ptr_;
    }

    // Overload the arrow operator
    T* operator->() const {
        return ptr_.get();
    }

    // Implicit conversion to the raw pointer
    operator T*() const {
        return ptr_.get();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr_;
};

// Example usage
class MyClass {
public:
    void display() const {
        std::cout << "This is MyClass" << std::endl;
    }
};

void functionThatNeedsRawPointer(MyClass* ptr) {
    if (ptr) {
        ptr->display();
    }
}

int main() {
    auto sharedPtr = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
    SharedPtrWrapper<MyClass> wrapper(sharedPtr);

    // Use the wrapper
    wrapper->display(); // Access through the wrapper
    functionThatNeedsRawPointer(wrapper); // Implicitly converts to raw pointer

    return 0;
}

And I would like something more like the following two-liner:
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T>::operator T*() {
    return this->get();
}

Unfortunately it does not compile. Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Do not implicitly convert smart pointers to pointers. There's a reason it's not there in the first place. If get() becomes excessive, which I think is not particularly likely, wrap the C functions instead.

As for adding members to a class you don't control, it's not possible and also for good reason. It would be a terrible idea if it were possible. Imagine what would happen to overload resolution.

Every call to get() is a statement to the compiler that you are taking charge of reference counting. It is up to you to make sure the C library does not hold on to the pointer and/or tries to free it. If you are annoyed by the frequent calls to get() make a copy of the shared_ptr and then extract a pointer from it once using get().

You can save a little typing by using &*ptr instead of ptr.get(). Whether that's an improvement is mostly down to your aesthetic preference.

Well, wrapping C function would be a nightmare: If I have a C function that takes 4 pointer parameters, and in one calling function, I wrapped some of them with std::shared_ptr and in another function some other, I would have to wrap the function 16 times to ensure it can be called either with the std;;shared_ptr or with the raw pointer independently.

The "annoyance" is actually good thing - every time you type or see .get(), it's a reminder that you need to be extra careful about ownership and lifetime. (The smart "pointers" are not about managing memory, they are about managing ownership.)

You could make the parameter of the function handle the implicit conversion to a raw pointer.
For example:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// Non-owning (possibly null) raw pointer.
// Intended for use as a parameter type; not as a member variable, local
// variable, global variable, or return type.
template <typename T>
struct raw_or_null_ptr {
    T* ptr;

    raw_or_null_ptr(T* ptr_) : ptr{ptr_} { }
    raw_or_null_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T> const& ptr_) : ptr{ptr_.get()} { }
    raw_or_null_ptr(std::shared_ptr<T> const& ptr_) : ptr{ptr_.get()} { }
    raw_or_null_ptr(T& obj) : ptr{&obj} {}
    raw_or_null_ptr(T&& obj) : ptr{&obj} {}

    auto operator->() const -> T* { return ptr; }
    auto operator*() const -> T& { return *ptr; }
    explicit operator bool() const { return ptr; }
};

// Example usage
struct MyClass {
    void display() const {
        std::cout << "This is MyClass\n";
    }
};

static void functionThatNeedsRawPointer(MyClass* a, MyClass* b, MyClass* c, MyClass* d, MyClass* e) {
    if (a) a->display();
    if (b) b->display();
    if (c) c->display();
    if (d) d->display();
    if (e) e->display();
}

namespace thunk {
static void functionThatNeedsRawPointer(raw_or_null_ptr<MyClass> a, raw_or_null_ptr<MyClass> b, raw_or_null_ptr<MyClass> c, raw_or_null_ptr<MyClass> d, raw_or_null_ptr<MyClass> e) {
    ::functionThatNeedsRawPointer(a.ptr, b.ptr, c.ptr, d.ptr, e.ptr);
}
}

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
    thunk::functionThatNeedsRawPointer(p, p, p, p, p);
}


operator T*  is missing (for foo_C(ptr);).

But the functionThatNeedsRawPointer function comes from the external library, which I don't have access to internally. Moreover this is a C library.

@MichaelA. • I've added a thunk function that acts as the go-between from the C++ side to the external C library side.

@Eljay I understand how this works, but the functions I play with don't have only 1 pointer, but may have upto 4/5 pointers. And I want to call the C function independently with raw pointer, or with std::shared_ptr for any of the 5 parameters this function takes. This would require to write 2**5=32 wrappers, which is obviously not a good option

@MichaelA. • The raw_ptr parameter type can be called with a raw pointer, or a unique_ptr, or a shared_ptr.  And you could add other types-to-pointers to it, if needed.  No need to make 32 wrappers for all the permutations — the raw_ptr is a one-stop-shop.

Changed the name from raw_ptr to raw_or_null_ptr to make the code more self-documenting.

@Eljay understood, and is a very good trick to know. But the issue is, it's not only one function I am dealing with, but tens, maybe a hundred. I don't want to wrap all these functions. This is why in my code, I was trying to work on std::shared_ptr itself so that it applies everywhere. And if you look at my wrapper, this is exactly what is done, but I was looking for a smarter way without having to wrap std::shared_ptr

In my own projects, I try to insulate my C++ code from external dependencies with an abstraction layer anyway.  I have found that having thunk functions is a convenient way to have an API abstraction and to firewall the external dependency.  My project (which is about 50 million lines of C++ code) has tens-of-thousands of these kinds of thunks.  I'm not saying this approach is the best approach, but I can say it does work.  And sometimes have the thunks proves useful for other purposes (debugging breakpoints, prints, marshalling, try/catch).
